# mysql while input field with same id/name/class post ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a code that bring products from mysql database then let user enter quantity and post it using javascript ajax code

EXAMPLE: ( the real result is from mysql while{ };

```
<form>
<input id="vpb_quantity" type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="vpb_change_quantity('product1');" /></form>

<form>    <input id="vpb_quantity" type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="vpb_change_quantity('product2');" /></form>

<form>    <input id="vpb_quantity" type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="vpb_change_quantity('product3');" /></form>

<form>    <input id="vpb_quantity" type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="vpb_change_quantity('product4');" /></form>
```

now this gets us an input box to enter quantity and press button to send the new quantity of the product
tried to change the id to id="vpb_quantity1", id="vpb_quantity2" etc butjava not geting the vpb_quantity value.
guess i have to change the code:

```
var vpb_quantity = $("#vpb_quantity").val();
```

we can't have same 'id' for all results , how can we change the bellow code to work with 'name' or 'class' instead of 'id'?

the script:

```
function vpb_change_quantity(item_id)
{
var vpb_quantity = $("#vpb_quantity").val();

$("div.checkout_user_info").hide();
$("div#checkout_user_info").hide();
$("div.shopping_cart_status").show();
$("div#shopping_cart_status").show();
var dataString = "item_id=" + item_id + "&vpb_quantity=" + vpb_quantity + "&page=change_quantity";
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "vasplus_programming_blog_shopping_cart_v4.php",  
data: dataString,
beforeSend: function() 
{
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
$("#response").html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading..."> Loading...<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />');
},  
success: function(response)
{
$("#response").html(response);
}
});
}
```

We need to change id to name or class & so we have to change that line:     var vpb_quantity = $("#vpb_quantity").val();
how can we do that?

Comment: please provide the real MySQL code, this is not SQL code. Also your problem/question is about your jQuery part and not the MySQL part, also please provide some more info how you retrieve the item_id variable. Also IDs should be unique

Comment: 1)  Why don't you change the id of the fields?  That's the simplest thing.
2)  You don't need to manually create the query string.  You can use $('form#formId').serialize() to let jQuery do it for you.
3) I'm not sure why this is a problem.  Each row is its own form, and you pass in the id, and quantity.  That should be unique enough for the server to handle.

Comment: the mysql was example only to explain the mysql result ,i've edited the post to make a clear example, the question is how to make java pull the posted input quantity not only the first one.

Comment: You should really ensure there is only one ID on a page, not only will this fail W3C but it's likely to come back and bite you in the ass at some point. But the simplest solution as @Nikhil says would be to add a class to the inputs you want to get and serialize based on that class or possibly by type number if these are the only HTML5 number type fields on the page.

Comment: if i change id to name will it work? and what should we change this line to in that case? var vpb_quantity = $("#vpb_quantity").val();

Comment: names and ids should be unique in the whole document